# Angular 2 pass local variable ngFor to a parent

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to implement event delegation, but I can't find a way to pass the local variable from ngFor to the parent.

```
  <ul (click)="doSomething(hero)">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of data">{{hero.name}}</li>
  </ul>
```

According to the event delegation technique, I need to click on the parent and check if the target is what I need and run the listener.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Not clear what you wants to achieve

Comment: Event delegation.

Comment: If what you are asking is how to handle a click event for each "li" element you could just <li *ngFor="let hero of data" (click)="doSomething(hero)">{{hero.name}}</li> and then within your doSomething function you will get the "hero" which you have clicked on

Comment: Read what event delegation is

Comment: _"I can't find a way to pass the local variable"_ As per definition passing a local(!) variable would not be delegation.

Answer (score 0):

This should be working

```js
export class YourComponent {
    data = ['a', 'b'];

    doSomething($event: any) {
        //$event.data is 'a'
    }
}
```

```html
    <ul (click)="doSomething($event)">
        <li *ngFor="let hero of data" (click)="$event.data = hero;">{{hero}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You are still adding a click event on the LI elements, so it's worth nothing, but thanks.

Comment: Right, because `hero` is a local variable and it has nothing to do with this event, so you should attach it to the event.
@ng2user Do you consider this answer correct?